# How to define ALB redirect in Terraform Fargate module?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-fargate

I'm new to Terraform and using the [Terraform Fargate](https://github.com/cn-terraform/terraform-aws-ecs-fargate) module to spin up a container, VPC, ALB, etc. I want the ALB to redirect TCP 80 -> 443 (with a 301) but don't see a way to define that. Right now, I'm just applying my Terraform run and fixing the ALB by hand in the AWS console. I've spent a couple days on this and can't seem to find the right keywords to draw a specific answer out of google.

Looking at [lb_http_ports](https://github.com/cn-terraform/terraform-aws-ecs-fargate/blob/main/variables.tf#L605) definition in the Fargate module, there aren't any variables defined for the redirect. The Terraform alb module does have these definitions under [http_tcp_listeners](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-alb/blob/master/examples/complete-alb/main.tf#L111) (`action_type`, `port`, etc) so I know there is a way to do this using Terraform.

Is there a way to 'extend' the Fargate module to apply these missing variables? I'm really not at a point yet where I can rewrite this whole module to include the pieces I need.

Comment: It doesn't look possible using that module. Since that's not an official AWS Terraform module, you should post in the issues section of that github project asking them how to do it.

Comment: Ok, thanks for checking it out.